# how to get the 3rd last value boo using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3

```
<a href="/app1/data/r.doc">  foo    </a>
<a href="/app2/data/r.doc">  boo    </a>
<a href="/app3/data/r.doc">  loo    </a>
<a href="/app3/data/r.doc">  goo    </a>
```

From the below `html` part,I have to find out 3rd last `text` of the ... Now to access that I wrote the below code(`used selenium-webdriver`):

```
all_links=driver.find_elements :tag_name, "a"

all_links.each do|link|

puts link.attribute("href")
puts link.text()

end
```

So now how to get the 3rd last value `boo` using `selenium-webdriver`? I am telling 3rd last as above `foo` there can be 100 more.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the third-last element of any array with a negative index:

```
array = [:foo, :bar, :baz, :qux]
array[-3] # => :bar
```

So in your case

```
all_links = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "a")
all_links[-3].text.strip # => "boo"
```

Note that you can use the `text` method rather than `attribute("text")`

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution as below:

```
all_links=driver.find_elements :tag_name, "a"

@linkscollection = Hash.new

all_links.each do|link|

text = link.attribute("text").strip
href = link.attribute("href").strip
@linkscollection[text]=href

end

#puts @linkscollection.length
print @linkscollection.keys[1] #=>boo
```